# Минимальная сумма 2 чисел, составленныхх из всех значений массива

Tags: python

Дан массив цифр. Нужно составить из этих цифр два числа таких, что их сумма минимальна. На выход выдать эту сумму. Каждая цифра из массива должна использоваться ровно 1 раз.

Например, `min_digits_sum([1,2,3])` = 12 + 3 = 15, а `min_digits_sum([3,2,1,4,5,6,9,8,7,0])` = 16047

Попробовал составлять числа из наибольших и наименьших значений массива:

```
s_arr = sorted(arr)

if len(s_arr) % 2 == 0:
    ss1 = ''.join(map(str, s_arr[:(len(s_arr)//2):]))
    ss2 = ''.join(map(str, s_arr[(len(s_arr)//2)::]))
    s = int(ss1) + int(ss2)
else:
    ss1 = ''.join(map(str, s_arr[:(len(s_arr)//2)+1:]))
    ss2 = ''.join(map(str, s_arr[(len(s_arr)//2)+1::]))
    s = int(ss1) + int(ss2)


print(s)
```

Также думал о том, что самые большие цифры должны уходить в младшие разряды, но не знаю, верно ли это.

Подскажите с решением

Comment: `0 0 1 1`. Ответ должен быть `2` или `20`? Строка с ведущим нулём `01` считатется за число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Также думал о том, что самые большие цифры должны уходить в младшие разряды, но не знаю, верно ли это.

Да, это верно. Вы шли по правильному пути :)) Но тут можно обойтись без функций `map`, `join` и так далее.

Итак, вот ваш код:

```
s_arr = [3,2,1,4,5,6,9,8,7,0]
n = len(s_arr)
s_arr = sorted(s_arr)
num1 = num2 = 0
for i in range(n):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        num1 = num1 * 10 + s_arr[i]
    else:
        num2 = num2 * 10 + s_arr[i]
print(num1+num2)
```

**Алгоритм:**

- приравниваем `n` к длине `s_arr`
- сортируем `s_arr` по возрастанию
- приравниваем `num1` и `num2` значение 0
- повторить `n` раз:

  - если шаг делится на 2:

    - `num1 = num1 * 10 + s_arr[i]`
  - иначе:

    - `num2 = num2 * 10 + s_arr[i]`
- печатаем сумму `num` и `num2`

**Вывод:**

```
16047
```

Помог ли мой ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Еще, как вариант:

```
s_arr = [3,2,1,4,5,6,9,8,7,0]
s = i = 0
arr = sorted(s_arr)
while arr:
    s += sum(arr[-2:])*10**i
    i += 1
    arr = arr[:-2]

print(s)  # 16047
```

код довольно простой, пояснять особо нечего: в цикле проходим по отсортированному списку, суммируем два последних элемента умножая сумму сначала на 1 потом на 10, затем на 100 и т.д., пока список не закончится.